# Calling an Angular1 service from a controller to collect data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a form with many views that will aggregate to a object containing user info. I have a component that has a form.js file:

```
import angular from 'angular';    
import FormController from './form-controller';
import FormService from './form-service';

export default angular.module('Form', [])
  .controller('formController', FormController)
  .service('formService', FormService));
```

form-service.js:

```
import angular from 'angular';    

export default class FormService {
  constructor() {
    this.master = {};
  }

 addData(user) {
   this.master = angular.extend(this.master, user);   
   return user; //don't really need to return this yet
  }
}
```

and form-controller:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import FormService from './form-service';  

export default class FormController {
  constructor() {
    this.service = new FormService;
  }
  update(user) {    
    this.service.addData(this.master);
  }    
}
```

So the problem is that data is not aggregating, probably because I'm instantiating a new service object in the FormController constructor. However, otherwise I get a

> formService2.default.addData is not a function

error message

I know this seems silly but I'm a bit new to angular and not really sure how I should be calling a service function from the controller.

Comment: Shouldn't you really be using Angular's dependency injection to inject `formService` into your controller? Otherwise, you're creating a new service each time the controller is instantiated. Also, what is `this.master` in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

A service is a singleton, so there is only one instance of your service in the whole application. If you need create more then one instance of your objects from your formService, then you should replace this:

```
.service('formService', FormService));
```

with this:

```
.factory('formService', FormService));
```

Will be interesting you inject the service inside the class, so you don't need to instantiate with `new FormService`.